# What linux capabilities are necessary for DRI (Direct Rendering Infrastructure)?

Tags: linux, docker, privileges

Background:

I'm looking to create a docker image that can run opengl.

To do that I followed the steps found [here](http://gernotklingler.com/blog/howto-get-hardware-accelerated-opengl-support-docker/), which worked like a charm.

The issue is that the instructions recommend that one use docker's `privileged` mode, which provides the docker container with *all* linux capabilities.

I'd like to replace `privileged` with the exact capabilities that I need to run DRI, and only those capabilities.

The problem is that I don't know what those are, or any way to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to pass `--device=/dev/dri:/dev/dri` to docker instead of `--privileged` if you're using an open source video driver.

For more details (and if you're using a closed source driver) the x11docker folks keep a wiki on the subject:
https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/wiki/Hardware-acceleration